# how to split a string matching a pattern in python

Tags: python, string, split

I have string looking like this:

```
'Toy Story..(II) (1995)'
```

I want to split the line into two parts like this:

```
['Toy Story..(II)','1995']
```

How can I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Is that the only string you want to split? If not, could you give a few more examples?

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that if that is the only string you want to split, I would just store it in its final form: l = ['Toy Story..(II)' '1995']

Comment: It will be difficult to automatically do the conversion from "Stroy" to "Story" for similar spelling errors, but apart from that, some simple string parsing or a simple regex will help.

Comment: -1: The title is useless.  Please change "what I want" to something that could be helpful to the thousands of people who look for help on this site every day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will get you started:

```
'Toy Stroy..(II) (1995)'.rstrip(')').rsplit('(',1)
```

Other than that, you can use `r'\s*[(]\d{4}[)]\s*$'` to match a four-digit number in parentheses at the end of the string. If you find it, you can chop it off:

```
s = ''
l = [s]
match = re.compile(r'\s*[(]\d+[)]\s*$').search(s)
if match is not None:
    l = [s[:len(match.group(0))], s[-len(match.group(0)):].trim]
```

Comment: For your second method, I think it is not suitable for my problem. You see, if the sting is "Toy Stoy(1000) (1995)". the method won't work well. do you think so?

Comment: Try it, it works since the regexp matches just one four-digit number at the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

One way is this:

```
s = 'Toy Stroy..(II) (1995)'
print s[:s.rfind('(')].strip()
print s[s.rfind('('):].strip("()")
```

Output:

```
Toy Stroy..(II)
1995
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions for that. See here: http://www.amk.ca/python/howto/regex/

Or you could use the split function and then manyally remove the parenthesis or other non desired characters. See here: http://www.python.org/doc/2.3/lib/module-string.html

Comment: The line may be complex, and It will be difficult to design a regular to work well.

Comment: If the line always ends with the year, a simple regex with something like (.*)\s*\((\d{4})\) should do the trick. You'll have the name of the movie in the first backreference and the year in the second.

Answer (score 0):

```
l[:-1].split("(")
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry that I give a simple example. But in real word, the line would be like this "Toy Stoy..(II) (1995)". In this case, your method will not work well.